# How to add dictionary element from beautifulsoup to json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, beautifulsoup

Can you help me how to import from dictionary to json file, I already get all tags from web but still confuse to save all tags. this is my code

```
array= []
data = {}
for divdata in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "ratio9_8 box_img fl mr10"}):
    for div in divdata.findAll('div', {'class': 'img_con lqd'}):
        for getatag in div.findAll('a', {'data-category': 'WP Kanal Berita'},href = True):
            for getimgtag in getatag.findAll('img',title=True,src=True):
                array.append(getimgtag['title'])
                array.append(getimgtag['src'])
                array.append(getatag['href'])
                data['title'] = array[0]
                data['image'] = array[1]
                data['link'] = array[2]
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

when running the program, I just get one dictionary

```
{"title": "......", "image": ".....", "link": "...."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your output statement in the loop where you are assigning data.  You are overwriting the data on each iteration.  If you change your code to be:

```
array= []
data = {}
for divdata in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "ratio9_8 box_img fl mr10"}):
    for div in divdata.findAll('div', {'class': 'img_con lqd'}):
        for getatag in div.findAll('a', {'data-category': 'WP Kanal Berita'},href = True):
            for getimgtag in getatag.findAll('img',title=True,src=True):
                array.append(getimgtag['title'])
                array.append(getimgtag['src'])
                array.append(getatag['href'])
                data['title'] = array[0]
                data['image'] = array[1]
                data['link'] = array[2]
                with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
                    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

It should give you what you want.

Alternatively you could do:

```
array= []
data = {}
data_list = []
for divdata in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "ratio9_8 box_img fl mr10"}):
    for div in divdata.findAll('div', {'class': 'img_con lqd'}):
        for getatag in div.findAll('a', {'data-category': 'WP Kanal Berita'},href = True):
            for getimgtag in getatag.findAll('img',title=True,src=True):
                array.append(getimgtag['title'])
                array.append(getimgtag['src'])
                array.append(getatag['href'])
                data['title'] = array[0]
                data['image'] = array[1]
                data['link'] = array[2]
                data_list.append(data)
data = {'data_list': data_list}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```